# Moving data from one table to another using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently moving data from table1(named sheet1) in sheet1 to table2(named sheet2) in sheet2 if a value exists. I am new to List objects, and am unsure how to go about this. Sheet 1 will have a lot of data, while sheet 2 will be an empty table at first. I plan to iterate through the data, and copy the data over, if it has a value.

```
'e will be coming from an array I have set up. 
e = "Sheet1"

Sub GatherData(ByVal e As String)
Dim Lo As ListObject, Ros As ListRows, e2 as String
Dim Tablesize As Integer, CurrentRow As Integer
Dim Sht1 As Worksheet
Set Sht1 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(e)
Set Lo = Sht1.ListObjects(e)
Set Ros = Lo.ListRows
Tablesize = Ros.Count

e2 = "sheet2"
Dim Sht2 As Worksheet
Set Sht2 = Worksheets(e2)
Set Lo2 = Sht2.ListObjects(e2)
Set Ros2 = Lo2.ListRows
Tablesize2 = Ros2.Count


    For CurrentRow = 1 To Tablesize
        If Lo.ListColumns("Name").DataBodyRange(CurrentRow) <> "" Then
        'nesting if loop when I add further functionality to check for further values in other columns            
               If Lo.ListColumns("Name_Value").DataBodyRange(CurrentRow) <> "" Then
               'add to new table on sheet 2
                'Lo2.ListRows.Add
                'sht1.Range("A" & CurrentRow).Copy sht2.Range("A" & Tablesize2)
                'sht1.Range("A" & CurrentRow).Copy sht2.Range("B" & Tablesize2)
                'sht1.Range("B" & CurrentRow).Copy sht2.Range("C" & Tablesize2)
                End If    
        End If

    Next CurrentRow
```

---

```
    How the table is set up for ex;

    Sheet 1                     Sheet 2
    Name   Value           Tablename  Name   Value
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim e As String
e = "Sheet1"

Dim Lo As ListObject, Ros As ListRows, e2 As String
Dim Tablesize As Integer, CurrentRow As Integer
Dim Sht1 As Worksheet
Set Sht1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(e) ''Edited this line for best practice
Set Lo = Sht1.ListObjects(e)
Set Ros = Lo.ListRows
Tablesize = Ros.Count

e2 = "sheet2"
Dim Sht2 As Worksheet
Dim Lo2 As ListObject, Ros2 As ListRows, Tablesize2 As Integer ''These variables were not dimensioned
Set Sht2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(e2) ''EDITED THIS LINE!!
Set Lo2 = Sht2.ListObjects(e2)
Set Ros2 = Lo2.ListRows

On Error Resume Next
Tablesize2 = Lo2.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count ''if no data rows error 91 is thrown
If Err.Number = 91 Then
    Tablesize2 = 0
ElseIf Err Then
    MsgBox ("An error has occurred, Error Number = " & Err.Number & " The Action is Cancelled")
    ''add other code to roll back changes
    Exit Sub  
End If

    For CurrentRow = 1 To Tablesize
        If Lo.ListColumns("Name").DataBodyRange(CurrentRow) <> "" Then
        'nesting if loop when I add further functionality to check for further values in other columns
               If Lo.ListColumns("Value").DataBodyRange(CurrentRow) <> "" Then ''EDITED THIS LINE!!
               'add to new table on sheet 2
                Lo2.ListRows.Add
                Tablesize2 = Lo2.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count      ''ADDED THIS LINE

                Lo2.DataBodyRange.Cells(Tablesize2, 1) = Lo.Name
                Sht1.Range("A" & CurrentRow + 1).Copy (Lo2.DataBodyRange.Cells(Tablesize2, 2))
                Sht1.Range("B" & CurrentRow + 1).Copy (Lo2.DataBodyRange.Cells(Tablesize2, 3))(xlPasteValues) ''ADDED LINE
                End If
        End If

    Next CurrentRow
```

`Tablesize2 = Ros2.Count` creates a condition where you can have no data in the table and a count of 0 or no data in the table and a count of 1, in order to avoid this problem I changed to `DatabodyRange.Rows.Count` which throws an error if there is no data, or a count of the data rows if there are 1 or more rows of data.

Note that instead of copying and pasting you could also do this:

```
Lo2.DataBodyRange.Cells(Tablesize2, 1) = Lo.Name
Lo2.DataBodyRange.Cells(Tablesize2, 2) = Sht1.Range("A" & CurrentRow + 1).Value
Lo2.DataBodyRange.Cells(Tablesize2, 3) = Sht1.Range("B" & CurrentRow + 1).Value
```